# Grep value from a column in csv file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

How can I search string in particular column using grep?

Example:

```
Name   age  place
Shruti 18   Delhi
Kiran  22   Chandigarh
```

I want to search display all the lines containing Chandigarh string in place column

Comment: you've tagged the question with `awk` and `grep`; please update the question to show your attempts at using `awk` and/or `grep` and the (wrong) results generated by your code; please also update the question to describe the format of the input file ... tab delimited? fixed width? something else?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Grep you can do

```
$ grep -P '^(([^\t]*)\t){2}Chandigarh' blah.tsv 
Kiran   22  Chandigarh
```

`-P` specifies perl-style regexes, and then `^` is the beginning of the line, `([\t]*)` is 0 or more of anything that isn't a tab (so, any column value), so then `(([^\t]*)\t)` is any column value followed by a tab, and finally `{2}` says we want 2 of those, thus putting `Chandigarh` in the third column.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk '!+__ { for(_ = NF;_;_--) { if (__ == $_) {
>                  __ = _; next } } } ___ == $__' __='place' ___='Chandigarh'
> ```

```
Kiran  22   Chandigarh
```

> - 1st part scans header row for matching column name `"place"`
> - 2nd
>   part does vanilla case-sensitive full-column string matching for `"Chandigarh"`